# Where can I specify bundle ID for iOS app in Bluemix Advanced Mobile Access service?

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, bundle-identifier, ibm-mobile-services

I created MobileFirst starter services on Bluemix for my existing Xcode project. Does anyone know where to specify the bundle ID for my iOS app? 
A few months ago, I could specify it by creating a new mobile client for custom authentication in Advanced Mobile Access (AMA) service. But now, the step to create mobile client is missing in configuring custom authentication and I have no idea where else to put the bundle ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently modified the way the security service (previously Advanced Mobile Access, now renamed to Mobile Client Access) is set up. Please note the following from [the blog post detailing the update](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/09/advanced-mobile-access-renamed-mobile-client-access/).

> You also no longer need to register your app’s bundle identifier with the Mobile Client Access service. In the previous version of Advanced Mobile Access, you had to register your iOS app’s bundle identifier before you could take advantage of authentication, logging, or operational analytics. With the Mobile Client Access service, this is no longer required, and it’s easier to get set up and running. Just connect your app and start working:

Objective-C for iOS

```
// initialize SDK with IBM Bluemix application ID and route
IMFClient *imfClient = [IMFClient sharedInstance];
[imfClient initializeWithBackendRoute:@"<APPLICATION_ROUTE>" backendGUID:@"<APPLICATION_ID>"];
```

(Swift available also)

Comment: Thanks, James, for the quick comment! It's clear now.